# Kafka on windows with SSL

Tags: windows, ssl, apache-kafka

I have a kafka broker installed on windows and it works fine, but I also need to run it with SSL. How can I use SSL for Kafka on Windows?

PS: Found just how to do it for Kafka on Linux.

Comment: Probably not much different than in Linux, what have you tried ?

Comment: JVM flags and JKS files indeed all work similarly on windows